# Trigger required event on form when click on the outside button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a snippet, what I'm trying to do is to get used of the required event on any of the input fields inside the form when click the next button which reside outside the form (means the form will halt and not be submitted and a html5 required notification will pop). Any ideas how to achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="test" value="" placeholder="your name" required />
  <button>save</button>
</form>

<button>Next</button>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve..

Comment: @Pekka: no, I dont want to trigger the click action on the save button inside the form. I want to use only the next button which reside outside the form to trigger the required event from any of the input fields that has a required property.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `<button>` element. In order for form validation to occur, you need to submit the form with a click on an `<input type="submit">`. Add one of those in but hide it from view.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="test" value="" placeholder="your name" required />
  <button>save</button>
  <input type="submit" class="hiddenSubmit" />
</form>

<button class="next">Next</button>
```

Then when the "Next" button is clicked, trigger a click on the hidden submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "button.next", function(){
    $(".hiddenSubmit").trigger("click");
  });

});
```

[Like so.](http://jsfiddle.net/h8qh74Lo/)

It'd be ideal if your form were constructed differently, but I'm assuming you're stuck to that layout.